¿Porque los scripts de las librerias que uso en mi web no cargan al publicar mi web en el IIS?
sobre la pregunta realmente se puede solucionar sencillamente si en vez de tener los scripts(.js) de las librerias como bootstrap, datatable, etc. los cambio por su cdn. Pero esto no creo que sea lo ideal ya que si uso una misma libreria en varios cshtml tengo que importar el cdn en esas vistas por lo que originalmente tengo en el archivo BundleConfig todos los archivos. Por ahora localmente funciona bien si tengo los scripts descargados en mi proyecto o si uso el cdn, pero al momento de publicar mi pagina en el IIS usando los archivos js de las librerias la pagina no esta tomando ninguna libreria, cuando ingrese un cdn de una libreria que uso como sweetalert2 en una vista y luego publique de nuevo la pagina ahora si funcionaba.
Entonces, teniendo eso en cuenta... Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto? de manera que pueda tomar bien los archivos de mis carpetas. Les comparto mi BunbleConfig:
/* BOOTSTRAP JS */
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"));

            /* VENDOR JS */
            bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/assets/vendor/js").Include(
               "~/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js",
               "~/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"));

            /* MAIN JS */
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/js").Include(
                 "~/assets/js/main.js",
                 "~/assets/js/datatables.min.js",
                 "~/assets/js/pdfmake.min.js",
                 "~/assets/js/vfs_fonts.js",
                 "~/assets/js/popovers.js",
                 "~/assets/js/jspdf.umd.min.js",
                 "~/assets/js/sweetalert2.min.js"
                 ));

            /* FILES CSS & BOOTSTRAP */
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/style.css",
                "~/Content/Site.css",
                "~/Content/datatables.min.css",
                "~/Content/sweetalert2.min.css"
                ));

            /* VENDOR CSS */
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/vendor/css").Include(
                "~/assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css",
                "~/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
                "~/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css"));

De esta manera tengo en mi archivo _Layout:
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")   
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/vendor/js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/assets/js")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Y este seria un ejemplo del error que me sale en la consola de la libreria:

Para aclarar mi proyecto es de ASP.NET MVC & .NET Framework 4.8. Les agradeceria mucho si me pudieran orientar un poco sobre este error ya que es la primera vez que publico un proyecto en IIS. :)

Habría que ver dónde va a buscar los archivo y porque va a esa ruta. Yo recomiendo nunca usar CDN, el autor se enoja, lo borra o peor aún ingresa código malicioso y tu ni te enteras (y ha pasado)

@Yussef Y como puedo saber donde busca los archivos? Perdon si no entiendo, pero como mencione en la publicación es mi primera vez publicando una pagina en IIS

En el navegador, en el error (la imagen que pusiste) debería salir donde va el navegador a buscar el archivo (si no aparece en la consola, en la pestaña de red seguro aparece). Con esa información puedes comparar "la ruta donde va a buscar" contra "la ruta real donde están los archivo" y desde ahí determinar que es lo que pasa. Generalmente hay una subcarpeta que falta o sobra

@Yussef Estas muy en lo cierto, de hecho me cambia la ruta. La ruta para que tome los archivos js de mi proyecto que especifique en en archivo bundleconfig solo deberia ser: assets/js y en cambio en el error me da esta ruta: /Combos/assets/js?v=8a-XpoJTg-qnGR3sPDotxtKoW7Mv98O7t_2I48VJ_G81
